# Is the "api" tag required?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [api](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) tag seems to be being used for several different concepts

This question is about the DD4T API
[Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 - PageContentAssembler](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/tridion-2011-sp1-hr1-pagecontentassembler)

This question is about the Deployer [Obtain PublicationPath from Deployer API](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/887/obtain-publicationpath-from-deployer-api)

This question which is about the Broker storage config file [Publishing Taxonomy to broker database](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/460/publishing-taxonomy-to-broker-database)

Should we:

a) make it a synonym for [content-delivery](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-delivery)? Which seems to be how it's being used.
b) rename it to something else [content-delivery-api](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-delivery-api)?
c) leave it

Comment: Isn't it possible to delete a tag?

Comment: It's not an option I have. I can merge it with another which I guess is effectively deleting it.

Comment: What happens if you remove the tag from all the questions it's on? I have the idea that tags only exist in the context of tagged questions.

Comment: deleting is not possible, but even if it would (like removing it from all known questions) does not solve anything, because ppl can always create it again. So it's better we find a correct usage of it by making it a synonym of something, else somebody will create it again at some point I'm sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does seem many content delivery questions are already about the API, whereas content management questions could potentially *not* be about code. We could keep this consistent with [configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration).

I think [api](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) adds some value in the same way [configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) lets people follow things related to setup. If [configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) appeals to those interested in infrastructure, maybe [api](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) appeals to programmers. I think it's a better tag than simply [code](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code). I agree with Chris--[api](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) can't represent just the Content Delivery API.

I could imagine a rule that "if it's not about content delivery, you can optionally add [api](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) to distinguish the question from non-api questions," would match the types of questions we have, but it seems silly and hard-to-maintain. Out of the options, I'd say leave [api](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) as part of a tag that better defines a question, similar to how we use [configuration](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) or [2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2011). If we only dealt with code, then it wouldn't add much and we could probably remove it completely.

Comment: I think I'm in agreement here Alvin.

Answer (score 5):

I would argue that the tag [api](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) is only useful in combination with other tags, and as such has no meaning on its own.

```
a) doesn't , as the API could easily refer to either a CD or CM API
b) doesn't really work, for the same reason as above
c) well... we should do something. Can we delete it and replace it with specific API tags for each API?
```

Just my 2 cents

Comment: I agree right now the tag API is only useful in combination with other tags but I do wonder, does using it in conjuction with those other tags actually add anything to the current tags given so many of the questions are actually about some api? Likewise would having specific API tags for each API actually add anything beyond the tags we currently have?

Comment: I agree that currently the `api` tag doesn't add much. We need more non-coding questions for it to matter. But apparently we don't have many question on how Tridion *functions*. ;-)